# GMail moves Exim4 emails into Spam

Tags: debian, email, email-server, exim, gmail

I am trying to setup email transfer to GMail.
This bash command in OS Debian:

```
echo "aaa" | mailx -r "xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx" -s"sdf" xxxxx.xxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

But all of my messages GMail moves into Spam.
I've already setup a lot of DNS data:

```
@   A       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
@   MX  2   @
@ SPF v=spf1 +a +mx ip6:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx ~all
@ TXT v=spf1 +a +mx ip6:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx ~all
_adsp._domainkey    TXT     dkim=all
_dmarc      TXT  v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:xxxxx.xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx
mail._domainkey     TXT     v=DKIM1;...VQIDAQAB
```

Of course, my server has got managed reverse DNS.
This a top part of my message in GMail:

```
Delivered-To: xxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com
Received: by xx.xx.xx.xxx with SMTP id xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
        Wed, 9 Dec 2015 09:31:29 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by xx.xx.xx.xxx with SMTP id xxxx.xx.xxxxx;
        Wed, 09 Dec 2015 09:31:29 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <xxxx@xxxxx.xxxx>
Received: from xxxxx.xxxx ([xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.xx
        for <xxxxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 09 Dec 2015 09:31:29 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx designates xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx designates xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=xxxxx@xxxxx.xxx;
       dkim=pass header.i=@xxxxx.xxx;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=xxxxx.xxx
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=xxxxx.xxx; s=mail;
    h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:To:From:Date; bh=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=;
    b=xxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=;
Received: from xxx by xxxxx.xxx with local (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx>)
    id xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xx
    for xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com; Wed, 09 Dec 2015 12:31:29 -0500
Date: Wed, 09 Dec 2015 12:31:28 -0500
From: xxxxx@xxxx.xxxx
To: xxxxxx.xxxxxxx@gmail.com
Subject: sdf
Message-ID: <xxxxx.xxx+xxxxxxxxxx%xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx>
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 6/20/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

**HOW TO FIX IT???**

I've already read a lot of information about this. But did not found any error.
I know this is post may be dublicated. But I have not found any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the email actually does arrive in your gmail account, albeit in the spam folder, you already got there most of the way. According to the email header gmail marks spf and dkim as passed, which means that's not the problem. You have configured reverse dns correctly as well.

For all practical purposes you have done all you can to increase the chance the email is delivered correctly which is a good thing. The reason that it is marked as spam may be shown in the header (if you didn't show it all) and can for example be because of a bayesian scan of the email body, perhaps it contains a url or certain text that may mark it as spam. Though in your example the body seems to only contain the string "***aaa***" which means if you would be sending an email that actually has some human created content (or output from a cronjob or such) it could pass the filter without a problem, try that out.

But it really is a bit of guessing here since we do not know the inner workings of gmail's spamfilters.

You should be able to mark the emails as not spam in gmail and move it to the inbox instead. You can also create filters in gmail that should prevent these emails from being marked as spam.

I am afraid I think there's not much else that could be done on your side since you did everything correctly. Perhaps try contacting gmail's helpdesk (yeah right).